# Parse HTML packs on WP8.1

Tags: c#, html, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am aware of HTMLAgilityPack but it doesn't support windows phone 8.1.
So is there anything else I could use to parse html codes?

For the moment I am getting the source code and using regex to grap what I want but this could be ruined with a small update/change of the website or the source code. + an html parser would be more reliable and easier.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my applications I am using a Portable Class Library version of HTML Agility Pack:
https://github.com/Deathspike/HtmlAgilityPack-PCL

Comment: That project's summary now includes the the text `Decrepated`, I assume it's deprecated.